# How to display data from uart on Raspberry PI 4

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, qml, uart

I'm new in the raspbian bios and programming language, I have problem with receiving data from the raspberry pi 4 uart (ttyS0). I have ADC converter of course, which returns me hexadecimal string with data.  The Przemytnik class is for connecting c++ language with qml, I would like to add a few classes in the future that's why I'm using the other class to reconvert data to qml. Sorry for my bad English, I'm still learning ;) I'm using QSerialPort library Could you help me with this?
SerialReader.h:

```
#ifndef SERIALREADER_H
#define SERIALREADER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QSerialPort>

class SerialReader : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString data READ data NOTIFY dataChanged)

public:
    explicit SerialReader(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    QString data() const;
    Q_INVOKABLE void readData();
    void writeData(const QString &data);

signals:
    void dataChanged();

private:
    QSerialPort m_serialPort;
    QString m_data;
};

#endif // SERIALREADER_H
```

SerialReader.cpp:

```
#include <SerialReader.h>
#include <iostream>

SerialReader::SerialReader(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {
    m_serialPort.setPortName("/dev/ttyS0");
    m_serialPort.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
    m_serialPort.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    m_serialPort.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    m_serialPort.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    m_serialPort.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);

    if (!m_serialPort.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        std::cerr << "Błąd portu szeregowego!";
    }
}

QString SerialReader::data() const { return m_data; }

void SerialReader::readData() {
    if (m_serialPort.isOpen() && m_serialPort.isReadable()) {
        m_data = m_serialPort.readAll();
        emit dataChanged();
    }
}

void SerialReader::writeData(const QString &data) {
    if (m_serialPort.isOpen() && m_serialPort.isWritable()) {
        m_serialPort.write(data.toUtf8());
    }
}
```

przemytnik.h:

```
#ifndef PRZEMYTNIK_H
#define PRZEMYTNIK_H

#include <QObject>
#include <SerialReader.h>

class Przemytnik : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(SerialReader* serialReader READ serialReader WRITE setSerialReader NOTIFY serialReaderChanged)

public:
    explicit Przemytnik(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    SerialReader* serialReader() const;
    void setSerialReader(SerialReader* serialReader);

signals:
    void serialReaderChanged();

private:
    SerialReader* m_serialReader;
};

#endif // PRZEMYTNIK_H
```

przemytnik.cpp:

```
#include <przemytnik.h>

Przemytnik::Przemytnik(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent), m_serialReader(new SerialReader(this)) {
    m_serialReader->readData();
}

SerialReader* Przemytnik::serialReader() const { return m_serialReader; }

void Przemytnik::setSerialReader(SerialReader* serialReader) {
    if (serialReader != m_serialReader) {
        m_serialReader = serialReader;
        emit serialReaderChanged();
    }
}
```

I also used `qmlRegisteredType` in main.cpp
And my simple main.qml code:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.3
import port 1.0

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Item{
        Przemytnik{
            id: przemytnik
        }
        Text {
            text: przemytnik.serialReader.data
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to change the code, but with no results. I don't know what I can do to fix that. I'm hoping that someone can help me.

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The problem is that you are reading the port when instantiating the object so there is probably no data at that moment. Use the port's readyRead signal to invoke readData

Comment: Is that a function from the library qserialport port?

Comment: Re. `"Is that a function from the library qserialport"`: sorry, but you really should read the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qiodevice.html#readyRead) (and perhaps the [examples](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtserialport-terminal-example.html)).

Comment: @G.M. why are you sorry? The OP should be sorry for asking such questions :)

Comment: If you have an IIO driver for the ADC, switch to it and use IIO architecture for getting data remotely.